# ASP.net Listview Hide Edit Button when Session Value equals a variable

Tags: asp.net, listview

I want to hide the edit button in the listview when a session variable is not equal to 2. When session is equal to 2 then I want the edit button to be visible.

My code is below.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="UserStoryID" DataSourceID="ShowProjectsTest">
           <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">


                   <td>
                       <asp:Label ID="StoryLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Story") %>' />
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <asp:Label ID="EstimatedTimeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EstimatedTime") %>'  />
                   </td>

                   <td>
                       <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" Font-Size="Small" />
                       <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" Font-Size="Small" />
                   </td>

                       <asp:Label ID="UserStoryIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserStoryID") %>' Visible="false" />
                       <asp:Label ID="ProjectIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectID") %>' Visible="false" />
                       <asp:Label ID="SprintIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SprintID") %>' Visible="false" />



               </tr>
           </AlternatingItemTemplate>

       </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Visible attribute to the edit button and then toggle it in the code behind.

Mark Up:

```
<asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" Font-Size="Small" Visible="false" />
```

Code Behind:

```
this.EditButton.Visible = (Session["Key"] as int) == 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Not to sure what to do with the code behind you gave me. Can you explain further ?

Comment: Put it in your page load method. If the Session variable is equal to 2 it will add the edit button to the page otherwise it won't.